# Удаление, редактирование, добавление БД через PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, post, mysqli, cms

Cобственно сам скрипт для добавления, удаления, редактирования конкретной таблицы работает. Вопрос как это сделать для таблицы, которую мы выбрали или ввели? Пытался через форму $_POST['name_table'] передать название таблицы, передает, но при нажатии на ссылку редактировать, поля пустые, также не работают функции удаления и добавления.

```
 $GLOBALS['link'] = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "passwd", "infoip");
if ( !isset( $_GET["action"] ) ) $_GET["action"] = "showlist";  

switch ( $_GET["action"] ) 
{ 
  case "showlist":    // Список всех записей в таблице БД
    show_list(); break; 
  case "addform":     // Форма для добавления новой записи 
    get_add_item_form(); break; 
  case "add":         // Добавить новую запись в таблицу БД
    add_item(); break;
  case "editform":    // Форма для редактирования записи 
    get_edit_item_form(); break; 
  case "update":      // Обновить запись в таблице БД
    update_item(); break; 
  case "delete":      // Удалить запись в таблице БД
    delete_item(); break;
  default: 
    show_list(); 
}

// Функция выводит список всех записей в таблице БД
function show_list() 
{ 
  $query = "SELECT `id`, `IP`, `Hostname`, `Ports`, `Mac_address`, `Mac_vendor`, `date` FROM `".$_POST['name_table']."`"; 
  $res = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$query ); 
 // echo $_POST['name_table'];
  echo '<h2>Список IP & Mask</h2>'; 
  echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">'; 
  echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>IP & Mask</th><th>Hostname</th><th>Ports</th><th>Mac_address</th><th>Mac_vendor</th><th>Date</th><th>Редактировать</th><th>Удалить</th></tr>'; 
  while ( $item = mysqli_fetch_array( $res ) ) 
  { 
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$item['id'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$item['IP'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$item['Hostname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['Ports'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['Mac_address'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['Mac_vendor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['date'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=editform&id='.$item['id'].'">Ред.</a></td>'; 
    echo '<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=delete&id='.$item['id'].'">Удл.</a></td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
  } 
  echo '</table>';
  echo '<p><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=addform">Добавить</a></p>';  
} 

// Функция формирует форму для добавления записи в таблице БД 
function get_add_item_form() 
{ 
  echo '<h2>Добавить</h2>';  
  echo '<form name="addform" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=add" method="POST">'; 
  echo '<table>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>IP</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="IP" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Hostname</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Hostname" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Ports</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Ports" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Mac_address</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Ports" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';  

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Mac_vendor</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Ports" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>date</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Ports" value="" /></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>'; 
  echo '<td><button type="button" onClick="history.back();">Отменить</button></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '</table>'; 
  echo '</form>'; 
}

// Функция добавляет новую запись в таблицу БД  
function add_item() 
{ 
  $IP = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['IP'] ); 
  $Hostname = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Hostname'] ); 
  $Ports = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Ports'] );
  $Mac_address = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Mac_address'] );
  $Mac_vendor = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Mac_vendor'] );
  $date = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['date'] );

  $query = "INSERT INTO `".$_POST['name_table']."` (IP, Hostname, Ports, Mac_address, Mac_vendor, date) VALUES ('".$IP."', '".$Hostname."', '".$Ports."', '".$Mac_address."', '".$Mac_vendor."', '".$Date."' );"; 
  mysqli_query ($GLOBALS['link'],$query ); 
  //header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
}

// Функция формирует форму для редактирования записи в таблице БД 
function get_edit_item_form() 
{ 
  echo '<h2>Редактировать</h2>'; 
  $query = "SELECT `id`, `IP`, `Hostname`, `Ports`, `Mac_address`, `Mac_vendor`, `date` FROM `".$_POST['name_table']."` WHERE id=".$_GET['id']; 
  $res = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'], $query ); 
  $item = mysqli_fetch_array( $res ); 
  echo '<form name="editform" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=update&id='.$_GET['id'].'" method="POST">'; 
  echo '<table>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>IP</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="IP" value="'.$item['IP'].'"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Hostname</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Hostname" value="'.$item['Hostname'].'"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Ports</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Ports" value="'.$item['Ports'].'"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';  

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Mac_address</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Mac_address" value="'.$item['Mac_address'].'"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';  

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>Mac_vendor</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="Mac_address" value="'.$item['Mac_vendor'].'"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';  

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td>date</td>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="date" value="'.$item['date'].'"></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';   

  echo '<tr>'; 
  echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>'; 
  echo '<td><button type="button" onClick="history.back();">Отменить</button></td>'; 
  echo '</tr>'; 
  echo '</table>'; 
  echo '</form>'; 
} 

// Функция обновляет запись в таблице БД  
function update_item() 
{
  $IP = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['IP'] ); 
  $Hostname = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Hostname'] );
  $Ports = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Ports'] );
  $Mac_address = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Mac_address'] );
  $Mac_vendor = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['Mac_vendor'] );
  $date = mysqli_escape_string($GLOBALS['link'], $_POST['date'] );

  $query = "UPDATE `".$_POST['name_table']."` SET IP ='".$IP."', Hostname='".$Hostname."', Ports = '".$Ports."', Mac_address = '".$Mac_address."', 
      Mac_vendor = '".$Mac_vendor."', date = '".$date."' WHERE id=".$_GET['id']; 
  mysqli_query ($GLOBALS['link'], $query ); 
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
} 

// Функция удаляет запись в таблице БД 
function delete_item() 
{ 
  $query = "DELETE FROM `".$_GET['name_table']."` WHERE id=".$_GET['id']; 
  mysqli_query ($GLOBALS['link'], $query ); 
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
} 

?>
```

Comment: Хм, а почему они должны быть полные, поля-то? Разные таблицы - разные поля. Сначала вам следует получить наименование полей из выбранной таблице, а потом на основании массива полей строить остальные действия.

Comment: Никогда не делайте так: "SELECT `id`, `IP`, `Hostname`, `Ports`, `Mac_address`, `Mac_vendor`, `date` FROM `".$_POST['name_table']."`";
У вас тут sql иньекция в чисто виде, и в целом очень советую почитать документацию и книги по теме веб разработки и php

Comment: @Visman а не может быть разных таблиц с одинаковыми полями?

Comment: @ConnorHolt  да тут в принципе один большой пример, как не надо писать на пхп.

Comment: @Visman в данном случае, у меня в таблицах одинаковые названия полей